# The entity type 'PessoaFisica' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Estou tentando gerar o migrations utilizando o comando:

> ```
> dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --context MyContext
> ```

e o mesmo está me retornando a seguinte mensagem.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'PessoaFisica' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured.

Em minhas classes possuo `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` herdando de `Pessoa` e `Funcionario` herdando de `PessoaFisica` (`public class Funcionario : PessoaFisica`).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
.ToTable("Funcionario");
```

Comment: Coloque todas essas classes, inclusive como `map` (as configurações) eu ainda não sei se isso funciona no core, existem coisas que ainda não funcionam!

Answer (score 1):

O que está a acontecer, pelo que me parece, é que ao usar o método TPH(Table Per Hierarchy) tu tens de mencionar o valor da coluna de descriminação.
ex:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/14/tip-12-how-to-choose-an-inheritance-strategy/

Para isso, no model builder, tens de fazer uma coisa parecida como:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
    .Map<Funcionario>(m => m.Requires("Descriminator").HasValue("FUNC"))
```

Comment: Estou a usar o EntityFramework Core. Eu não tenho o Entity<>().MAP<>()

Comment: Ok. Então provavelmente, será isto que falta: modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Tipo")
            .HasValue<Funcionario>("FUNC");